To find X path of the capital city of country but by using countries X path
Hi guys I want to find the X path of the capital city of the country by using the country.Help me in finding the X path. I have used independent and dependent X path but not able to find it.
Link of website - https://www.countries-ofthe-world.com/capitals-of-the-world.html
I tried to find the X path of the city by using country name.
enter image description here

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

//table//td[text()='Mali']/following-sibling::td

You can replace the country using a variable depending on the programing language u use. So that when you pass the country name, this xpath would point to capital of the country

Could you please ping one example.

"//table//td[text()='"+CountryName+"']/following-sibling::td"   this is in Java where Country name is the variable
